# Is it possible to use SQL syntax like FROM DUAL in JPA?

Tags: jpa, jpql

I am trying to create an independent project regardless of the type of DB using JPQL's @Query .

How do I implement the syntax below in JPA?

```
SELECT MY_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL
```

Comment: I use nativeQuery as false in @Query.

Comment: You probably need to run your query as raw SQL, and as such, you might as well use `DUAL`.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you mean it has to be something like this to use as a DUAL? "SELECT d FROM DUAL d".
I am asking how to implement this.

Comment: There is no `DUAL` table in JPQL.  My guess is that you need a native query, or else find a workaround.

Comment: If you can't use DUAL in JPA, do you know how to implement functions like SYSDATE and NEXTVAL?

Comment: You don't.  At least you can't use `SYSDATE` from JPA.

Comment: So is NEXTVAL not possible even in JPA?

Comment: Using `NEXTVAL` in the context of JPA doesn't even make sense, because `NEXTVAL` has nothing to do with the Java entities sitting behind your JPA layer.

Comment: DUAL is Oracle specific. It's even not a SQL standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short answer:

For this kind of query, it's more productive to just use `nativeQuery = true` and use it normally.

To make it database agnostic as you want, you could theoretically just create a `DUAL` table in the new database.

#### Long answer:

The short answer is what you are actually looking for. But for the sake of other people who might fall here through Google for other related reasons though, if you *really* want it, you could theoretically transform Oracle's `DUAL` table into an entity by using `@Subselect` like so:

```java
@Table
@Entity
@Subselect("SELECT dummy FROM DUAL")
public class DualEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "dummy")
    private String dummy;
}
```

Where `dummy` is the sole column in the `DUAL` table.

Although this doesn't seem very useful at first glance because most of this kind of queries are much easier to run as native queries, this does let us create repository interfaces for database functions when they aren't related to any actual tables in the database. Example:

```java
@Repository
public interface DualRepository extends JpaRepository<DualEntity, String> {

    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT MY_OWNER.MY_FUNCTION(:myParameter) FROM DUAL")
    String myFunction(Long myParameter);

}
```

Which again, this function should probably be part of your code and not part of the database, but older applications tend to have this kind of stuff around. Procedures could also be called through `@Query`/`@Procedure` and could also benefit from this kind of mapping.

Comment: Just to add that if you don't plan on possibly changing to another database, you could define the entity directly on the table definition just like any other entity as so: `@Table(schema = "SYS", name = "DUAL")`. The idea for using `@Subselect` is tied to their wish of keeping this database agnostic, so they could just create a `DUAL` table in the new database.